# Render curly brackets of Ember property as handlebars delimiters

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following property in my controller:

```
panelTemplate: '<ul><li>Components:</li><li>{{multi-input-comp}}</li><li>{{modal-dialog-comp}}</li><li>End</li></ul>'
```

In the template corresponding to the controller I want the two components (multi-input-comp and modal-dialog-comp) to be displayed in the list.

But writing `<div>{{{panelTemplate}}}</div>` in .hbs would display the following:

- Components:
- {{multi-input-comp}}
- {{modal-dialog-comp}}
- End

Is there any way to make Handlebars treat the curly brackets of the property panelTemplate as delimiters so I would get the result in the image?

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CSML.png)

Comment: change the property name

Comment: You can not do this without hacking deep into embers core itself.

Comment: @Lux: Yeah it seems that I have to do that or maybe change the whole concept I'm following. Btw here is the question with the actual example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785717/rendering-curly-brackets-as-handlebars-delimiters because in this question I gave an over-simplified example which created a misunderstanding.

Comment: @userGS from where do you get this property? Cant you just use handlebars instead of an html containing property?

Comment: You can make it dynamic. You could have an array `components:['multi-input-comp','modal-dialog-comp']` and then loop over it in handlebars `{{#each components as |c|}}{{component c}}{{/each}}`. You could even build your own meta language, with component and plaintext parts, where you use a handlebars if to either use the component helper or just show the content.

Comment: But there is some cases where I have to put an non-component (let's say a simple div) between two components. If I write the code you suggested I won't be able to I think.

Comment: @userGS you can always add a property `c.isComponent` or so and if its false do `{{{c.value}}}` and otherwise `{{component c.value}}`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the curly braces form your property and render the component with the component helper:

```
{{component componentName}}
```

For more information on the component helper take a look at the ember docs: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_component

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This answer works for the example I gave.  I tried to make the property as simple as possible but in reality the property I'm dealing with is a little more complicated. In fact I have a panel that contains multiple components and html tags. I'll edit it to make it more specific.

Comment: Well you can make your property as complicated as it gets. It can be a computed property that does a lot of stuff but in the end you just need one  string that is the name of the component you want to render.

Comment: For some reason, I am unable to edit it. Here is the property: panelContent: '<ul><li>{{component1-name}}</li><li>{{component2-name}}</li>' In the template .hbs I want to call it like this <div>{{panelContent}}</div> instead of <div><ul><li>{{component1-name}}</li><li>{{component2-name}}</li></ul></div>

Comment: So the thing is that I want to pass not only the component name but also the html tag that contains it which would cause an error if I use the component helper you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

So after all, I was able to find a solution:

```
//app/components/panel.js
panelTemplate: '<ul><li>Components:</li><li>{{multi-input-comp key="E-mails"}}</li><li>{{partial-test}}</li><li>End</li></ul>',
templateName: "temp-panel" //make sure it does not contain an upper case character

//app/templates/components/panel.hbs
{{partial (render-template panelTemplate templateName)}}



 //app/helpers/render-template.js
import Ember from 'ember'; 
export function renderTemplate(params/*, hash*/) {
    var obj= params[0];
    var panel  = params[1];
    var htmlContent =  Ember.HTMLBars.compile(obj);
    Ember.TEMPLATES[panel] = htmlContent;
    var template = Ember.TEMPLATES[panel];
    return panel;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(renderTemplate);
```